# map-reduce to construct recommendation list

Tags: python, mapreduce, hive

I have a collection of files, each file has 3 fields

```
USER, ITEM, SCORE
U1, I1, S1
U1, I2, S2
U2, I1, S3
U1, I4, S4
...........
```

The output I need is

```
 U1   [I1, I2,....I5]    # top 5 items, in the desc of scores, additional items are drooped
 U2   [I1]               # top items if less than 5
```

Anyone can give the pseudo code for the algorithm, I know how to get the aggregation, what confuses me is how to chop off additional items using map-reduce. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic idea would be to have your mapper emit key-value pairs: (user, (score, item)).

Hadoop then groups by user, and sorts by (score, item). You may need to include some custom comparison logic to get it to sort by score first, and probably also in reverse order, since you want the 5 greatest.

Then, your reducer can simply collect the first five elements it encounters for each key. In pseudo-code:

```
def map(user, item, score):
  emit(key=user, value=(score, item))

def compareValues(value1, value2):
  return -1 * compare(value1.score, value2.score)

def reduce(key, values):
  emit(key, values[0:5])
```

Alternatively, I noticed you included a Hive tag... this is possible using pure Hive, assuming you're using version 0.11 or greater:

```
select user, collect_set(item) from (
  select user, item, row_number() over (partition by user order by item desc) as r
  from foo
) t where r <= 5 group by user;
```

Sadly, it looks like Hive isn't smart enough to translate this into the simple algorithm described above; it uses two MapReduce jobs.

Edit: I just noticed you asked nearly this same question earlier. Is there some problem you had with dimamah's answer on that question? The fact that he and I independently came up with the same query just with different variable names gives me confidence that this is the canonical way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what 'map-reduce' is, but here is a solution using `heap`.

```
from collections import defaultdict
from heapq import heappush, heappop

top_items = defaultdict(list)
max_items = 5 
data_file = 'data_file'

for line in open(data_file):
    user, item, score = line.split(',')
    if len(top_items[user]) >= 5:
        heappop(top_items[user])
    heappush(top_items[user], (score, item))
```

`top_items` will contain a list of the top five items (as (score, item) tuples) for each user.